# Browserify Ember.js 1.7

Tags: ember.js, browserify, browserify-shim

The latest 1.7 Ember beta breaks my gulp-browserify task (config below) with the following exception:

`Error: browserify-shim needs to be passed a proper browserify instance as the first argument.`

Gulp had been browserifying Ember happily up until 1.7 (and continues to do so for latest 1.6 using the config below).  I noticed in the release notes for 1.7 that the module system has undergone some upheaval.

***My question is:*** Is this a legitimate bug in Ember (or perhaps Browserify)?  Or is Ember no longer intended to be used with tools like browserify going forward, in favor of some other specific approach?

#### Exact config:

*packages.json :*

(Note, this particular site already has jQuery embedded via a standard script tag, hence the need for browserify-shim, and the `global:` notation on the jquery dep.)

```
{
  "browser": {
    "handlebars": "./scripts/lib/handlebars-v1.3.0.js",
    "ember": "./scripts/lib/ember-1.7.min.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:jQuery",
    "handlebars": "Handlebars",
    "ember": {
      "exports": "Ember",
      "depends": [
        "handlebars:Handlebars"
      ]
    }
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^4.1.11",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.5.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

*gulpfile.js :*

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify');


gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src([
              './app.js',
            ])
        .pipe(browserify({
            insertGlobals: false,
            debug: false
        })).pipe(gulp.dest('./Scripts/build'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);
```

*app.js :*

```
var Ember = require('ember');
```

#### Basic Repro:

in a test dir:

- `npm install gulp browserify gulp-browserify browserify-shim`
- ensure paths exist to deps:

  - `"handlebars": "./scripts/lib/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"`
  - `"ember": "./scripts/lib/ember-1.7.min.js"`
- add my example `app.js` above
- add my `packages.json` above
- add my `gulpfile.js` above
- run `gulp`
- Swap out Ember 1.7 for 1.6 to see success.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get Ember 1.7 (or newer) working?

Comment: Not with  `gulp-browserify` itself, no.  However, I was able to at least use browserify with Ember 1.7 by manually creating an additional gulp task in gulpfile.js, ala:

`gulp.task('browserify-manually', function () {
    run("browserify ./path/to/ember/app.js -o ./path/to/output.js").exec();
})`

I didn't pursue it any further as EmberCLI is now the best practice for this sort of thing.

Comment: I appreciate you following up @user1889765 .  I hadn't quite figured that out the other day, but have been using ember-cli successfully since yesterday :)

Comment: What are you browserifying? As far as I know, Ember hasn't provided an npm package since 1.0.0-pre.2 (though it will start to soon).